# ZohoCRM Module getRecords PHP

Tags: php, zoho

I'm using the [ZohoCRM PHP SDK](https://github.com/zoho/zcrm-php-sdk) to attempt to pull all `Account` records from the CRM and manipulate them locally (do some reports). The basic code looks like this, which works fine:

```
    $account_module = ZCRMModule::getInstance('Accounts');
    $response = $account_module->getRecords();
    $records = $response->getData();

    foreach ($records as $record) {
        // do stuff
    }
```

The problem is that the `$records` object only has 200 records (out of about 3000 total). I can't find any docs in the (minimally / poorly documented) SDK documentation showing how to paginate or get bigger result sets, and the Zoho code samples in the dev site don't seem to be using the same SDK for some reason.

Does anyone know how I can paginate through these records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@dakdad was right that you can pass in the page and per page values into the `param_map`. You also should use the `$response->getInfo()->getMoreRecords()` to determine if you need to paginate. Something like this seems to work:

```
$account_module = ZCRMModule::getInstance('Accounts');
$page = 1;
$has_more = true;

while ($has_more) {
    $param_map = ["page" => $page, "per_page" => "200"];
    $response = $account_module->getRecords($param_map);
    $has_more = $response->getInfo()->getMoreRecords();

    $records = $response->getData();
    foreach ($records as $record) {
        // do stuff
    }
    $page++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `getRecords()` [method seems to accept](https://github.com/zoho/zcrm-php-sdk/blob/cca65b0e874b69e222d95969104f2a69ea3c91f1/src/crm/crud/ZCRMModuleRelation.php#L104) 2 parameters. This is used within some of [their examples](https://github.com/zoho/zcrm-php-sdk/blob/cca65b0e874b69e222d95969104f2a69ea3c91f1/samplecodes/customeview.php#L21). You should be able to use those params to set/control pagination.

```
$param_map = ["page" => "20", "per_page" => "200"];
$response = $account_module->getRecords($param_map);
```